# can't parse IP address from PDF file, no error, just empty

Tags: python, regex, pdf, tika-python

I'm using Tika to parse IP addresses from a PDF file. Below is my code:

```
import tika
from tika import parser
import re

 
# Press the green button in the gutter to run the script.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    tika.initVM()
    # opening pdf file
    parsed_pdf = parser.from_file("static_hosts.pdf")
    text = parsed_pdf["content"]
    regex = '(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$'
    match = re.findall(regex, text)
    print(match)
```

I have tested the regex online and found that they work properly. I even tried these but none of them work:

```
regex = '(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$'
regex = ^'(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$'
regex = r'(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$'
```

Could you please show me where I missed?

Thank you.
Huy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:

```
import tika
from tika import parser
import re

# Press the green button in the gutter to run the script.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    tika.initVM()
    # opening pdf file
    parsed_pdf = parser.from_file("static_hosts.pdf")
    text = parsed_pdf["content"]
    regex = r'\b((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})\b'  # modified regex with capturing group
    matches = re.finditer(regex, text)
    ip_addresses = [match.group(0) for match in matches]
    print(ip_addresses)
```